# How These Product Images Were Designed?

Tags: background, product-design

eCommerce websites are known at least to me for their average product images but there are exceptions like images of green tea product below which I wanted to get you opinion about:

[image]

This is one beautiful product but is this photo or manipulated image? I mean does it look too good to be real? I was thinking it's product image combined with background.

Here's next:

[image]

And final - product on a white background. Did they remove background it had initially?
[image]

Do these look real to you because I contemplate if it's designed or 3D rendered.

Assuming it's designed, how much time do these take to make and how much do you think designers charge for this kind of work?

Comment: The problem with this question my friend, is that if we keep this open, we set a precedent for allowing people to ask this. The thing is, this could be asked a gazillion times, with a bagillion different images, and none would be a duplicate of the others. For that reason, I'm voting to place on hold because it's too localised/specific to one case. Welcome to GD SE, and we're happy to have you.

Comment: The second image appears to be a well lit photo but at a closer look it seems that they have added the packet into the photo

Comment: I think there is more here than just a design.  The actual photography is a key to the overall images you've posted.  I would also suggest referencing our [Photography Stack](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) but make sure to do a search first because I think they already have similar questions to this.

Answer (score 2):

If they were compiled from various shots, it may only take a couple hours to assemble the final image.

I've done photorealistic 3d in the past, and I don't see the need for this shot to be recreated in a computer.

These are just well lit photographs.

Comment: Agreed.  As someone who has spent years working with product images and has experience with 3D modeling/animation, these are simply photographs.  I don't even think they are compiled from several images, but if they were, it looks like only a background was added.

Comment: A mate of mine - specializing in photographing shiny objects/glass etc uses a very large opaque dome with a little hole to place the camera lens through - so it omits any unwanted reflections, then he places drapes or shade on the outside and lights objects through the dome. This allows to keep the reflection consistent.

Comment: The tea packet is a render in every case (the same render, in fact), and was composited in (and not well, either); most of the rest looks rather like manipulated stock photography. There are subtle errors in all of the pictures that indicate things having been moved around as 2D representations rather than as 3D objects (things grounded on the wrong plane, occupying more space than would actually exist, shadows and reflections being other than what reality would permit, even when the bajillion reflector/flag cards that a product/food photographer would use are taken into account).

Comment: I have Pentax Optio 6-megapixel point&shoot camera and mini-tripod. Would it be enough to shoot product against white wall? I am trying to achieve something that looks like final photo above.